# Getting the average price of certain groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

Currently have a dataframe which is:

```
price     type                 randomc1     randomc2   randomc3
2         Dumpling
1         Milk Based Drinks
2         Dumpling
3         Milk Based Drinks
7         Cold Cuts
5         Cold Cuts
```

Wanted to get the average of prices of the similar types.

wanted output:

```
type                        average
Dumpling                       2
Milk Based Drinks              2
Cold Cuts                      6
```

also, there are about 100 different "types". so, ideally would want to get every "type" to be printed.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
edit: output to print(df.to_dict()) 

{'Dish_Type': ['Dumpling',
  'Dumpling',
  'Milk Based Drinks',
  'Milk Based Drinks',
  'Dumpling'],
 'Dish_Price': ['$9.95', '$7.95', '$8.95', '$8.95', '$9.95']}
```

Comment: Friendly question, if you say "groupby and average" as the title of the question, have you actually tried groupby and average? `groupby('type')['price'].mean()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df.assign(Dish_Price=df['Dish_Price'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float))
         .groupby('Dish_Type', as_index=False)
         .agg(Dish_Average=('Dish_Price', 'mean')))
print(out)

# Output
           Dish_Type  Dish_Average
0           Dumpling      9.283333
1  Milk Based Drinks      8.950000
```

Setup:

```
data = {'Dish_Type': ['Dumpling', 'Dumpling', 'Milk Based Drinks',
                      'Milk Based Drinks', 'Dumpling'],
        'Dish_Price': ['$9.95', '$7.95', '$8.95', '$8.95', '$9.95']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: @Pavan. Can you check if it works for your case, please?

Comment: @Pavan for future questions please try to be as accurate as possible with your issue from the start. This is a complete different problem than the one initially posted.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I understand correctly, it shouldn't matter how many different `type`s you have, all of them will be considered when using `groupby()`. Have you tried:

```
df.groupby('type',as_index=False).agg(average=pd.NamedAgg('price','mean'))
```

Comment: `df.groupby('type')['price'].mean().rename('average').reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you, I find your comment very useful! To keep it diverse I have edited with another option of achieving the same output!

Comment: `df.groupby('type', as_index=False).agg(average=('price', 'mean'))` :-P

Comment: Thanks again! I guess I'll just leave as-is, a little bit more explicit but with no changes in the output :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher yeah, tried this before. but getting the same error. 

Error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @Corralien getting an error. 
Error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

any idea what to do here?

Comment: @Pavan. Does it work with your sample?

Comment: @Corralien nope.

edited the question with a part of my actual dataset. does this help?

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df.to_dict())` (`df` is your sample dataframe)

Comment: Need the whole dataframe. `print(df.head(5).to_dict('list'))`

Comment: You have to strip `$` before!